# No such signal when porting from Qt4.8 to Qt5.5

Tags: qt5, porting, signals-slots

We are currently trying to port an application from Qt4.8 to Qt5.5, and we are having issues with signals connections at runtime.

We are using the old syntax for signals and slots, which is still supported, and we obtain messages like "no such signal" at runtime under Qt5.5 whereas the execution worked well under Qt4.8.

For example, we have the following connect :

`connect(_vuePalette, SIGNAL(paletteModifiee(Pointeur<LUT>, Pointeur<Fonction>, TypeValeurVue, bool)), this, SLOT(paletteModifiee_SLOT(Pointeur<LUT>, Pointeur<Fonction>, TypeValeurVue, bool)));`

The message generated at runtime is :

> QObject::connect: No such signal VuePalette::paletteModifiee(Pointeur, Pointeur, TypeValeurVue, bool) in vueimage.cpp:83
>   (sender name: 'VuePalette')

_vuePalette refers to a class "VuePalette" wich is derived from QWidget and which contains the Q_OBJECT macro, and this refers to a class named "VueImage" which is derived from multiple classes derived from QObject, and "VueImage" contains the Q_OBJECT macro too.

The signal and the slot are respectively defined in the "signals" section of class "VuePalette" and in the "public slots" section of class "VueImage".

Does someone have a hint on the matter ?

Best regards,

Anthony

Comment: Please show some relevant code and the *actual* error message.  Better still, provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As an aside, if you try using the new syntax for the connection that's causing the problem you'll probably get some useful diagnostics from the compiler.

Comment: With the new syntax, we have no error message at runtime. The problem is that we have a lot of signals, slots and connect, because our application is quite big. We would prefer to keep using the old syntax rather than using the new one.

Comment: To help diagnose a bit further you could -- immediately before the call to `connect` -- call `_vuePalette->metaObject()` and use the returned `QMetaObject` to query the `signal` signatures.  Also, take a look at the preprocessor output to make sure the string generated by the `SIGNAL` macro is as expected -- just in case it's being redefined somewhere (although, based on what you've shown that seems very unlikely).

Comment: Please add *at least* the headers of the class involved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies.

I believe I've found what the problem is : in the "connect" statement, "Pointeur" is a QSharedPointer, so "LUT" and "Fonction" classes need to inherit from QObject and to contain the Q_OBJECT macro.

Sorry, I didn't find it before, but if it can help someone it would be worth it :).